# How to detect if a unique entry has been added to an array, and append to it with an input based on that unique entry?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, user-input

I'm creating a user interface program that tracks my daily progress while I'm learning to play the bass guitar.

In this program I'm creating arrays for all the info I'm tracking, in addition to an array that tracks the frequency of how much I practice a particular band. This is a portion of the program:

```
import numpy as np

count = 1

complete_arr=[]
artists_arr=[]

while count <= 3:

    # Inputs
    time_in = input("Daily Time: ")
    pa_in = input("Playing Ability: ")
    enj_in = input("Enjoyment: ")
    a1_in = str(input("Artist 1: "))
    a2_in = str(input("Artist 2: "))
    a3_in = str(input("Artist 3: "))
    notes_in = str(input("Notes: "))

    # Append to Artist matrix
    artists_arr.append([a1_in, a2_in, a3_in])

    # Append to complete matrix
    complete_arr.append([count, time_in, pa_in, enj_in, a1_in, a2_in, a3_in, notes_in])

    count += 1


# Transform into numpy arrays
complete_arr_np = np.asarray(complete_arr)
# print(complete_arr_np)
artists_arr_np = np.asarray(artists_arr)
print(artists_arr_np)

# Counts the number of times a unique artist appears
(unique, counts) = np.unique(artists_arr_np, return_counts=True)
band_count = np.asarray((unique, counts)).T
print(band_count)
```

Lets say over this sample period I practice band A 3 times, band B 1 time, and band C 1 time. This leaves 4 empty entries. Which running this gives me:

```
print(artists_arr_np)
[['A', 'B', ''], ['A', 'C', ''], ['A', '', '']]

print(band_count)
[['' '4']
 ['A' '3']
 ['B' '1']
 ['C' '1']]
```

Everything works as expected, but here's the issue. I want a way to detect once a unique band has been detected, and then append it with an input of what that band's genre is. So after running this code, 3 new bands (technically 4 including the empty entry) are detected: A, B, C. Ideally, after running the code, I want to be asked to input what each unique band's genres are. Resulting in this:

```
[['' '4' '']
 ['A' '3' 'Rock']
 ['B' '1' 'R&B']
 ['C' '1' 'R&B']]
```

How do I go about doing this? I imagine it will involve a combination of if and for loops, but not sure how exactly. If its not obvious, I'm new to python so the answer may be simpler than I think. The frequency is irrelevant but I feel this should be where the genre info is stored.

Comment: After having tried to extend your framework for a bit, I am pretty sure you want to use a different data type. A low-level option would be a dictionary with the artist names as keys. But if you are willing to use/learn pandas, that seems like a pretty good fit for your application as well. Would either data type be an option for you?

Comment: I eventually was able to figure it out using dictionaries, doing a similar thing to what you're talking about. Thank you though. I actually started this with pandas in mind but for a variety of reasons decided against it.